# When i am keeping request to shoutcast server for genres to display in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

when i am keeping request to shoutcast server for genres to display in windows phone7.i am getting the response like this 

460
Missing required parameterREFERRER
 i am not getting the genres to display .but it is displaying in browser. all sites can i display in windows phone7 except shoutcast server..please help sir.and this is my code

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           DoWebClient();

```
    }

    private void DoWebClient()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();

        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://api.shoutcast.com/legacy/genrelist?k=ar1CybnF1NXzbH9Z"));
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted +=new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
    }

    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
        {
            string data = reader.ReadToEnd();

        }
    }
```

in data it is getting response like that..

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line:

```
webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = "http://api.shoutcast.com";
```

in DoWebClient  as follow:

```
private void DoWebClient()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();

    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer]
        = "http://api.shoutcast.com"; 


    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://api.shoutcast.com/legacy/genrelist?k=ar1CybnF1NXzbH9Z"));
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
}
```

I also recommend you to use RestSharp library for this kind of query on xml files.

Regrads,